# Using nested parameters with template in Azure Pipelines yaml file

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there any way to use nested within `parameters` on `azure-pipelines.yml`?
The example below is wrong...

```
# my-template.yml
parameters:
steps:
- ${{ each pf in parameters.pf }}:
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish ${{ pf.rid }} ${{ pf.output }}'
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ pf.output }}.zip'
```

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
steps:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
  - windows:
      rid: 'win-x64'
      output: 'Foo.exe'
  - macos:
      rid: 'osx-x64'
      output: 'foo'
```

Comment: Also googling around atm...

Comment: Maybe [Iterative insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) can help you?

So maybe group `windows` and `macos` under `platforms` and "mark" it as an array?

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked your example a little bit to make it work:

```
# my-template.yml
parameters:
  pf: []

steps:
- ${{ each pf in parameters.pf }}:
  - script: echo ${{ pf.rid }} ${{ pf.output }}
    displayName: 'Publish ${{ pf.rid }} ${{ pf.output }}'
```

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
steps:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    pf:
    # windows
    - rid: 'win-x64'
      output: 'Foo.exe'
    # macos
    - rid: 'osx-x64'
      output: 'foo'
```

You could find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates#iterative-insertion) about templates iterative insertion.

Although I suspect what you want to do could be better achieved using `strategy` and `matrix` like the following:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
strategy:
  matrix:
    windows:
      imageName: "vs2017-win2016"
      output: 'Foo.exe'
    macos:
      imageName: 'macos-10.13'
      output: 'foo'

pool:
  vmImage: $(imageName)

steps:
- script: echo $(output)
  displayName: 'Publish'
```

You could find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline#build-across-multiple-platforms) about build across multiple platforms.